# What front-end grid layout system supports both Fixed and Fluid at the same time?

Tags: html, responsive-design, fluid-layout, grid-layout, fixed-width

I've come across many popular grid system (ie: bootstrap, foundation, skeleton, neat, profound, etc...) but none of them are able to support my desired UI scenario:

Fixed Sidebar (ie: 240px) with the rest fluid (ie: 100%).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the grid layout at Pure CSS (http://purecss.io/layouts/email/) is capable of supporting fixed sidebars and the rest fluid.

The link shows the sample layout that achieves fixed-fluid support.